# for loop with zip in python

Tags: python, loops

I want to use zip to iterate to existing Lists.

I did that with the code below. Currently the output is just Name --> Name.

How do I use the new creates list or if that's not possible the other lists to print following sentence:

“#NAME is #AGE years old, and they can be called at #NUMBER”. Is it possible to accomplish this in a single loop?

```
    birth_years = {"Alice": "1990", "Bob": "1990", "Carol": "1995", "Felix":"1995","Max":"1995","Chris":"1998","Lea":"1998","Linn":"1998","Julia":"1998"}
    book = {"Alice": "+1554", "Bob": "+1885", "Carol": "+1006", "Felix":"+1604", "Max":"+1369","Chris":"+1882","Lea":"+1518","Linn":"+1742","Julia":"+1707"} 


   def test(birth_years, books):
      new_list = []
      for birth_year, book in zip(birth_years, books):
        new_list.append(f'{birth_year} -> {book}')
      return new_list

   print(test(birth_years,books))
```

Thanks!!

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is not the problem here. The problem is your `for` loop will simply loop over the keys in the dictionary, rather than the keys and values (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/14193797))

The correct way of doing this is:

```py
birth_years = {"Alice": "1990", "Bob": "1990", "Carol": "1995", "Felix":"1995","Max":"1995","Chris":"1998","Lea":"1998","Linn":"1998","Julia":"1998"}
books = {"Alice": "+1554", "Bob": "+1885", "Carol": "+1006", "Felix":"+1604", "Max":"+1369","Chris":"+1882","Lea":"+1518","Linn":"+1742","Julia":"+1707"} 


def test(birth_years, books):
    new_list = []
    for [name, birth_year], [unused, number] in zip(birth_years.items(), books.items()):
        new_list.append(f'{name} is {2022 - int(birth_year)} years old, and they can be called at {number}')
    return new_list

print(test(birth_years,books))
```

Comment: Hey 
thanks for your answer. 

What is unused, number for?

Comment: I name it unused because it is unused :). Specifically, both `name` and `unused` store the name.

Comment: Is it also possible to something like this, that you won't get every name in the output?

Comment: I just tried to implement name = input() but it doesn't work. Does it not work because "name" is already used?

Comment: Then I tried something like for ___ in: \n: if name in birth_years \n:return new_list but it also does not work. Can you explain me maybe why?

Comment: I used \n hier so that you know I didn't write it just next to each other.

Comment: 1) Yes, you can create a dict which key's are the names, and value are the string

Comment: 2) you have to create the dict :) so you could use the input